# Is there a way to force a filter in all sqlalchemy queries on a certain model?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to make sure that whenever a query is being written for some user data, a certain filter is used, to not mix up user data, e.g. for a model called User with columns col_A, col_B, where col_A is compulsory:

`User.query.filter_by(col_A=...)` should work,

`User.query.filter_by(col_A=..., col_B=...)` should work,

but `User.query.filter_by(col_B=...)` should raise an error,

as well as `User.query.filter(User.col_B=...)` should raise an error.

Is this possible? Or if not, what is the easiest workaround?

Comment: Is the required value always known? Something like `is_deleted=False`? If yes maybe this can help: [Adding global WHERE / ON criteria](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_events.html#adding-global-where-on-criteria)

Comment: The required value is an int. Essentially I want the equivalent of is_required=True, but not for adding a row, for querying a row.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to solve this problem so the closest solution was to add a class method:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from app import db

from sqlalchemy import false
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import TIMESTAMP


class Users(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
    email = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False, index=True)

    is_deleted = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, server_default=false(), nullable=False)
    created_at = db.Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), default=datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc), server_default=db.func.now(), nullable=False)

    @classmethod
    def query_active_users(cls):
        return cls.query.filter_by(is_deleted=False)
```

Call it as follows:

```
users = Users.query_active_users().all()
```